# how to use clouldformation trigger cloudWatch event forward logs to SQS queue

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

I have the following cloudformation template to create a cloudwatch event , a SQS queue , SQSQueuepolicy to allow cloudwatch forward logs to SQS queue whenever s3 objects are updated

However ; after template completed succesfully. I don't see log in SQS queue unless I go to ( via aws console) "cloudwatch"--> chose my event --> click till step2 event detail 'add permission to SQS queue"  --> update event

I think the missing part might be that I need a "RoleArn" in event Target in order to grant permission. However; AWS:SQS:QUEUEPOLICY does not return an ARN.
How Can I do this with cloudFormation ?

Thanks!

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Resources": {
    "LucyQueue": {
        "Type": "AWS::SQS::Queue",
        "Properties": {
            "QueueName": "LucySQS"
        }
    },
    "LucyQueuePolicy": {
        "Type": "AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy",
        "Properties": {
            "PolicyDocument": {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Id": "arn:aws:sqs:ca-central-1:805182230944:LucySQS/SQSDefaultPolicy",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Sid": "Sid1513273009724",
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": "*",
                        "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
                        "Resource": {
                            "Ref": "LucyQueue"
                        },
                        "Condition": {
                            "ArnEquals": {
                                "aws:SourceArn": {
                                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                        "LucyEventRule",
                                        "Arn"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Queues": [
                {
                    "Ref": "LucyQueue"
                }
            ]
        }
    },

    "LucyEventRule": {
        "Type": "AWS::Events::Rule",
        "Properties": {
            "Description": "LucyEventRule",
            "EventPattern": {
                "source": [
                    "aws.s3"
                ],
                "detail-type": [
                    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
                ],
                "detail": {
                    "eventSource": [
                        "s3.amazonaws.com"
                    ],
                    "eventName": [
                        "PutObject",
                        "UploadPart",
                        "CreateMultipartUpload"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "State": "ENABLED",
            "Targets": [
                {
                    "Arn": {
                        "Fn::GetAtt": [
                            "LucyQueue",
                            "Arn"
                        ]
                    },
                    "Id": "lucy_event1",
                    ***"RoleArn" : "Do i need this ? if yes, How to get the Arn"***
                }
            ]
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I found the issues is that i put wrong resourceID in QueuePolicy

A Working template:

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Resources": {
    "LucyQueue": {
        "Type": "AWS::SQS::Queue",
        "Properties": {
            "QueueName": "LucySQS"
        }
    },
    "LucyQueuePolicy": {
        "DependsOn": [
            "LucyQueue",
            "LucyEventRule"
        ],
        "Type": "AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy",
        "Properties": {
            "PolicyDocument": {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Id": "LucyQueuePolicy",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Sid": "AWS_Lucy_event",
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {
                            "AWS": "*"
                        },
                        "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
                        "Resource": {
                            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                "LucyQueue",
                                "Arn"
                            ]
                        },
                        "Condition": {
                            "ArnEquals": {
                                "aws:SourceArn": {
                                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                        "LucyEventRule",
                                        "Arn"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Queues": [
                {
                    "Ref": "LucyQueue"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "LucyEventRule": {
        "Type": "AWS::Events::Rule",
        "Properties": {
            "Description": "LucyEventRule",
            "EventPattern": {
                "source": [
                    "aws.s3"
                ],
                "detail-type": [
                    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
                ],
                "detail": {
                    "eventSource": [
                        "s3.amazonaws.com"
                    ],
                    "eventName": [
                        "PutObject",
                        "UploadPart",
                        "CreateMultipartUpload"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "State": "ENABLED",
            "Targets": [
                {
                    "Arn": {
                        "Fn::GetAtt": [
                            "LucyQueue",
                            "Arn"
                        ]
                    },
                    "Id": "lucy_event1",
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

}